# How to pass data between react native screens?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Hey I am new to react native. So basically I have a stack navigator with two screen option: Screen 1 (Default) and Screen2. I already set up a button so that when pressed it will take me to Screen 2. 
So in Screen1 I have an array displayed as scrollview component. Now when i press the button to go to screen2 I want to pass some of the array values to that screen2 component. What is the best way to do it? Thank you :)

I am really new so my attempts are kinda dumb. I tried importing the Screen1 component and calling the array values via this.state but no access.

Comment: Please, share the code you tried with

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The easiest way to pass the data is when you are navigating. To do that it is better that you put your array in a state an then use the following method:

```
onPress=()=>{
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
          yourArray: this.state.yourArray, });
      }
}
```

Then in the next screen(Screen2) you can find the array(your data) in the props.So in your constructor in scrren2 you can find the data here:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var params = props.navigation.state.params.yourArray;

}
```

Also to come back to your previous screen without touching your states you can use this code in your back button:

```
  const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
      goBack();
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I did it a bit differently tho, instead of storing it in var params, I just stored it in side screen2 state.

Comment: Sorry for my delay, nice to hear that.

Comment: what if we are using a tab to navigate?

Comment: @Jared: What do you mean by a tab? Can you explain more?

Comment: In your example the user is navigating to the next screen by pressing a button. How do you pass the data to the next screen of the user is pressing an icon on the bottom tab navigator to get to the other screen?

Comment: @Jared: Well, you have to ask this in another question, because it is not related to the topic. However, you can call navigation in the onPress function of any tab or icon. You could use TouchableOpacity to make an icon as a button. I hope I could help.

Answer (score 3):

To pass data from Screen1 to Screen2. Here we're storing the array in a state.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {array: this.state.array})}
```

To get the data from Screen1 in Screen2

```
this.props.route.params.array
```

The source of this response is official documentation. I have tried it as well because the above solution didn't work for me. For more information you can go to this [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params).