# Proper way to navigate back and forward my list items in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I am quite new to React Native and now I am kind of building my mobile app (previously implemented using jQuery and PhoneGap) from the beginning and I need an advice how to achieve the following:

On my main dashboard I have a list of mail boxes (React FlatList)

```
1. MailBox1
2. Mailbox2
3. Mailbox3
```

Then, after a specific mailbox was clicked I want to list all of the items inside of it (on a new screen/component/page):

```
1. MailBox1_Item1
2. MailBox1_Item2
```

Each of the mail items has its own details. After a mail item was clicked I want to be able to display its details on a new screen/component/page.

```
MailBox1_Item1 was created on 10/10/18
MailBox1_Item1 was created by SomeUser
etc.
```

The specific thing here is that I want to be able to navigate back when I am on the screens for details and mail items.

My app so far is using a tab navigator from here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation"
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

import HomeTab from './HomeTab'
import SettingsTab from './SettingsTab'

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen: HomeTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
          <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
        )
    }
  },
  Settings:{
    screen: SettingsTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
          <Icon name="ios-settings" color={tintColor} size={24}/>
        )
    }
  }
},
{
  //router config
  initialRoutName: 'Home',
  order: ['Home', 'Settings'],
  //navigation for complete tab navigator
  navigationOptions:{
    tabBarVisible:true
  },
  tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor:'red',
    inactiveTintColor:'grey'
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

and my dashboard is on the 'Home' tab.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942539/how-to-pass-data-between-react-native-screens/53942641#53942641

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is, just use a `StackNavigator` for your Dashboard route of the Tab, and your Stack navigator should contain the following routes

- MailList (Component to show mail list)
- MailItemList (Component to show list of items associated with specific mail)
- ItemDetail (Component to show detail for item)

The code should look like :

```
const dashboardStack = createStackNavigator({
  MailListScreen: {screen: MailList},
  MailItemListScreen: {screen: MailItemList},
  ItemDetailScreen: {screen: ItemDetail},
});
```

with this in hand, you should use `componentDidMount` of each component to initiate your network operation to fetch required data to show it to the screen, and for the screens which depend on the previous like list item screen to fetch list of items for given mail, just pass the `id` of the mail to the next screen and use that id to initiate the network call to fetch the desired data.

You can pass the id (in general, data) from one route (screen component) to other using `params` like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('MailItemListScreen', {id: 1});
```

The above line describes a navigation from current screen lets say from `MailListScreen` to `MailItemListScreen` and also carrying a payload of info as second parameter in the `navigate`.

I would recommend you read the react-navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) first.