# It is possible to return to previous screen with data on react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Let's say our current stack is ScreenA -> ScreenB. How can I return to ScreenA with a result (data) from ScreenB? Similar to android `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`

Edit: The goal is to return to ScreenA from ScreenB with a result, keeping ScreenA state if possible.

Comment: you need to make callback function and assign the variable as global.

Answer (score 0):

you can just navigate to ScreenA with parameters.
In your ScreenB, add the following to navigate:

```
const ScreenB = ({navigation}) =>{
       ...
       navigation.navigate("ScreenA",{data});
       ...
```

In your ScreenA, you listen for it.

```
const ScreenA = ({navigation, route}) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
     //this block listens for data change, then act on it.
    },[route.data]);
...

}
```

Comment: I'll have to check this, but doing this won't make de Stack ScreenA -> ScreenB -> ScreenA? If not, will ScreenA keep previous state?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942539/how-to-pass-data-between-react-native-screens).

Screen 1:

```
onPress=()=>{
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
          yourArray: this.state.yourArray, });
      }
}
```

Screen 2:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var params = props.navigation.state.params.yourArray;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In this example, we will input the value in the first screen and get it into the second screen.

The value (param) is passed as an object in the first screen to the navigation.navigate function as:

this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })   
The same value (param) is read in the second screen as:

this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)
```